Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$
I tried integration by parts
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^{1}\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}&=2\int_{0}^{1}\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\left.2x\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\right|_{0}^{1}-2\int_{0}^{1}x\left(\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)}{1+x^{2}}+\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}-2\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)}{1+x^{2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}-2\left(I+J\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Evaluting $J$ is relatively easy
$$\begin{aligned}
J&=-\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}}\\
&=-\left(\left.\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{1+x^{2}}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\right)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos^2\left(u\right)}{1+\sin^{2}\left(u\right)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}\qquad\left(x=\sin\left(u\right)\right)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{2}{1+\sin^2\left(u\right)}-1\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\cos^2\left(u\right)+2\sin^2\left(u\right)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1\mathop{\mathrm{d}u}\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\left(\sqrt{2}\tan\left(u\right)\right)}}{1+\left(\sqrt{2}\tan\left(u\right)\right)^{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=\left.\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\tan\left(u\right)\right)\right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}\pi
\end{aligned}$$
However I'm stuck at evaluating $I$. How to evaluate this integral?

Thanks everyone, the final result is
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\boxed{\frac{\pi^{2}}{4}-\left(\sqrt{2}-1+\ln\left(4-2\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\pi}$$

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{x\sin^{-1}x}{1+x^2}dx\overset{IBP}{=}\frac12\sin^{-1}x,\ln(1+x^2)\bigg|0^1-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
$$\overset{x=\cos t}{=}\frac{\pi\ln2}4-\frac12\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln(1+\cos^2t)dt\overset{\tan t=x}{=}\frac{\pi\ln2}4-\frac12\Re\int{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(\sqrt2-ix)-\ln(1-ix)}{1+x^2}dx$$
Closing the contour in the upper half-plane
$$I=\frac{\pi\ln2}4-\frac\pi2\Big(\ln(1+\sqrt2)-\ln2\Big)=\frac{3\pi}4-\frac\pi2\ln(1+\sqrt2)=0.2487...$$

The integral is approximately 0.6686484663. I do not know if there is a closed-form expression.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\sin^{-1}x}{1+x^2}dx=0.2487...$$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Carcsin%28x%29%7D%7B1%2Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx

@Svyatoslav. Mathematica provides a lonng result

@Claude Leibovici, this is strange; it seems that the case isn't very complicated. WA (free option) even gives an analytical expression...

@Svyatoslav. Sory, I made a mistake

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin ^{-1} x \ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1+\sin ^2 x\right) d x \quad \textrm{ via }x\mapsto \sin x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \left(1+\frac{1-\cos 2 x}{2}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{1}{4} \int_0^\pi \ln (3-\cos x) d x \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2-\frac{1}{4} \pi \ln \left(\frac{3+2 \sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \cdots (*) \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}[3 \ln 2-2 \ln (1+\sqrt{2})]
\end{aligned}
$$
$(*)$ obtained by putting $b=-1$ and $c=3$ in my post.

I shared it because the two methods are different.

For the antiderivative
$$I=\int \frac{x \sin ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac 12 \int \Bigg(\frac{\sin
   ^{-1}(x)}{x-i}+\frac{\sin^{-1}(x)}{x+i} \Bigg)\,dx$$ Now, we need to use
$$\sin ^{-1}(x)=-i \log \left(i x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$ to get the result in terms of polylogarithms and use
$$\int\frac{\sin^{-1}(x)}{x+a}\,dx=-\frac i 2 t^2+t \log \left(1-2 i a e^{it}-e^{2 i t}\right)+ $$
$$i
   \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{e^{i t}}{ia-\sqrt{1-a^2}
   }\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{e^{i t}}{ia+\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)\right) $$ where $t=\sin^{-1}(x)$.
Using the bounds
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{x \sin ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac{ \pi  }{4}\left(3 \log (2)-2 \sinh ^{-1}(1)\right)$$

Let $y=\arcsin x$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{y \sin y}{1+\sin ^2 y} \cos y d y \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{y \sin (2 y)}{1+\frac{1-\cos (2 y)}{2}} d y \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{y \sin (2 y)}{3-\cos (2 y)} d y \\
& =\frac{1}{4} \int_0^\pi \frac{y \sin y}{3-\cos y} d y
\end{aligned}
$$
Via integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{4} \int_0^\pi y d(\ln (3-\cos y)) \\
& =\frac{1}{4}[y \ln (3-\cos y)]_0^\pi-\frac{1}{4} \int_0^\pi \ln (3-\cos y) d y\\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2- \frac{1}{4}   \pi \ln \left(\frac{3+2 \sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\cdots(*)\\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}[3\ln 2-2 \ln (\sqrt{2}+1)]
\end{aligned}
$$
(*) obtained by putting $b=-1$ and $c=3$ in my post.
